# Ansible - Tagging Azure running VMs

Tags: azure, ansible

Today I've been working in finding the best way to tag running VMs in Azure automatically from Ansible.

The first approach was using `azure_rm_virtualmachine` module, but it works fine at the time of deploying a new VM. When the VM is up and running, that is another history, mostly when the deployment has been done with custom images.

```
  - name: Tag my VM
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      resource_group: myresourcegroup
      name: myvm
      admin_username: ansible
      admin_password: mypassword
      virtual_network_name: myvnet
      virtual_network_resource_group: myvnetrsg
      vm_size: Standard_D2_v2
      state: present
      started: no
      append_tags: True
      image:
        name: mycustomimage
        resource_group: myimagesrsg
      tags:
        env: "dev"
```

See: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/35235 solved in 2.7 but still not working with Custom Images.

So the question is how doing it with running VMs? How changing old tags and adding new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is using `azure_rm_deployment` together with `azure_rm_virtualmachine`.

With `azure_rm_virtualmachine` we register facts and add them to a variable:

```
  - name: Azure Facts
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      name: myvm
      resource_group: myrsg
    register: myvm
```

Then, deploy a VM using a JSON Template with `azure_rm_deployment` but keeping the important values for the VM:

> Note: The variables are for reference, work with them properly to keep then clean and manageable:

```
- name: Create Azure VM from ARM template with public IP
    azure_rm_deployment:
      state: present
      deployment_name: mydeployment
      location: mylocation
      resource_group_name: myresorcegroup
      wait_for_deployment_completion: yes
      template: "{{ lookup('template', 'azure.json') }}"
      parameters:
        tags:
          value: "{{ vmtags }}"
        adminUsername:
          value: "{{ myvm.ansible_facts.azure_vm.properties.osProfile.adminUsername }}"
        adminPassword:
          value: mypassword
        imageName:
          value: "{{ myvm.ansible_facts.azure_vm.properties.storageProfile.imageReference.id | basename }}"
        imageResourceGroup:
          value: myimagesrsg
        dnsLabelPrefix:
          value: "{{ myvm.ansible_facts.azure_vm.properties.networkProfile.networkInterfaces[0].properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.publicIPAddress.properties.dnsSettings.domainNameLabel }}"
        vmName:
          value: myvm
        ComputerName:
          value: "{{ myvm.ansible_facts.azure_vm.properties.osProfile.computerName }}"
        vmResourceGroup:
          value: myrsg
        nicName:
          value: "{{ myvm.ansible_facts.azure_vm.properties.networkProfile.networkInterfaces[0].name }}"
        virtualNetworkName:
          value: "{{myvm.ansible_facts.azure_vm.properties.networkProfile.networkInterfaces[0].properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.subnet.id.split('/')[-3] }}"
        publicIPAddressName:
          value: "{{ myvm.ansible_facts.azure_vm.properties.networkProfile.networkInterfaces[0].properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.publicIPAddress.name }}"
        subnetName:
          value: "{{ myvm.ansible_facts.azure_vm.properties.networkProfile.networkInterfaces[0].properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.subnet.id | basename }}"
        vmSize:
          value: "{{ myvm.ansible_facts.azure_vm.properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize }}"
        storageAccountType:
          value: "{{ myvm.ansible_facts.azure_vm.properties.storageProfile.osDisk.managedDisk.storageAccountType }}"
```

The password is not going to change, the VM Name and Resource Groups are known already and the tags is a dictionary like this:

```
  vars:
    vmtags:
        MyFirstDay: "Saturday"
        Env: "dev"
```

And the JSON Template?

The JSON is the standard Azure Template, but with the tags added as an **object**:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "tags": {
            "type": "object"
        },
        "adminUsername": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "adminPassword": {
            "type": "securestring"
        },
        "vmName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "ComputerName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "imageName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "imageResourceGroup": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "vmSize": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "vmResourceGroup": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "virtualNetworkName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "nicName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subnetName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "dnsLabelPrefix": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "publicIPAddressName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "storageAccountType": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
        "publicIPAddressType": "Dynamic",
        "privateIPAddressType": "Dynamic",
        "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/16",
        "subnetPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
        "vnetID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
        "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetID'),'/subnets/',parameters('subnetName'))]",
        "sshKeyPath": "[concat('/home/',parameters('adminUsername'),'/.ssh/authorized_keys')]",
        "hostDNSNameScriptArgument": "[concat('*.',resourceGroup().location,'.cloudapp.azure.com')]"
    },
    "resources": [{
            "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
            "name": "[parameters('publicIPAddressName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "publicIPAllocationMethod": "[variables('publicIPAddressType')]",
                "dnsSettings": {
                    "domainNameLabel": "[parameters('dnsLabelPrefix')]"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
                    ]
                },
                "subnets": [{
                    "name": "[parameters('subnetName')]",
                    "properties": {
                        "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetPrefix')]"
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "name": "[parameters('nicName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', parameters('publicIPAddressName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [{
                    "name": "ipconfig1",
                    "properties": {
                        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "[variables('privateIPAddressType')]",
                        "publicIPAddress": {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',parameters('publicIPAddressName'))]"
                        },
                        "subnet": {
                            "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "tags": "[parameters('tags')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('nicName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('ComputerName')]",
                    "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                    "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
                },
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "imageReference": {
                        "id": "[resourceId(parameters('imageResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Compute/images', parameters('imageName'))]"
                    },
                    "osDisk": {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'_OsDisk')]",
                        "createOption": "FromImage",
                        "managedDisk": {
                            "storageAccountType": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [{
                        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('nicName'))]"
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically this is a first approach and the naming variables, way of applying, etc will change in a more optimised way. I will update this when improving it.